# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n5^{2n-2}x^{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n5^{2n-2}x^{2n+1}$

I am wondering how one would be able to solve this series?

Comment: Begin by differentiating the geometric series and its formula. You can rearrange this series into one that matches the form necessary.

Comment: By changing parameters I get $\frac{1}{125} \sqrt{z}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^n$. Can it help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You may start from the useful **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+r+r^2+...+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ you get
$$
1+2r+3r^2+...+nr^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kr^k=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{(1-r)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)r^{n}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1. \tag2
$$

Then, using $|r|<1$, let $n \to \infty$ in $(2)$ and put $r:=5^2x^2$ in the obtained identity.